# Criando uma estrutura multi-nível para componentes no AngularJS + ES6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

Estou criando uma aplicação robusta utilizando o AngularJS sobre o ES6 e preciso montar uma estrutura para que fique organizada a lógica dos componentes da aplicação. Basicamente, minha aplicação trabalha com inúmeros módulos e, estes são estruturados em pacotes por exemplo:

```
app          -> módulo global da aplicação
 |-foo       -> submódulo
 |  |-bar    -> subcomponente foo.bar
 |-bin       -> submódulo
 |  |-bar    -> subcomponente bin.bar
```

Estou procurando uma forma de definir as declarações desses elementos dentro do angular. O problema é que não consigo acessar um componente que esteja dentro de um submódulo de app, assim:

**arquivo main.js**

```
import angular from "angular";
import foo from "./foo/foo"; // -> sub-módulo da aplicação
import bin from "./bin/bin"; // -> sub-módulo da aplicação

const app = angular.module("app",[foo,bin]);
```

**arquivo ./foo/foo.js**

```
import angular from "angular";
import bar from "./bar/bar"; // -> bar componente

export default angular.module("foo",[bar]);
```

**arquivo ./foo/bar/bar.js**

```
import angular from "angular";
import template from "./bar.html";

export default angular.module("bar",[
]).component("bar",{
  templateUrl: __dirname + "/bar.html",
  controller:{
    constructor(){
      this.name = "foo.bar;
    }
  }
});
```

A idéia direta é trabalhar como `namespaces` como tenho no PHP 7 ou C#, JAVA, etc.
Existe alguma forma de poder estruturar esses componentes com submódulos?